# How to replace keys stored in string with values stored in another table in Impala

Tags: sql, join, impala

I have an Impala table that stores keys as strings
there is schema of that table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_actions_t
 (
    `useractionid` BIGINT,
    `streamid` VARCHAR,
     PRIMARY KEY(useractionid)
 )
 PARTITION BY HASH PARTITIONS 16
 STORED AS KUDU
```

also, I have a dictionary table:

```
CREATE TABLE stream_dict_t
     (
        `streamid` BIGINT,
        `stream` varchar,
         PRIMARY KEY(streamid)
     )
     PARTITION BY HASH PARTITIONS 16
     STORED AS KUDU
```

There are simplified data in that tables:

```
insert into devl_mlc.user_actions_t values (1, '[1,2,3]'), (2, '[2,3]')
insert into devl_mlc.stream_dict_t values (1, 'daily'), (2, 'weekly'), (3, 'monthly')
```

Which gives:

for table *stream_dict_t*

```
1   daily  
2   weekly 
3   monthly
```

and for table *user_actions_t*

```
2   [2,3]
1   [1,2,3]
```

I want to combine two tables, but I can't use regular join due to streamid defined as a string.

Expected result:

```
2 [weekly,monthly]
3 [daily,weekly,monthly]
```

I tried to use Impala string functions but I can't quite figure out how to create one query that can handle the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the find_in_set function, you just need to remove the extra brackets from your string with the list of keys and verify if index is greater than 0

Example:

```
select find_in_set("1", replace(replace("[1,2,3]","]",""),"[","") ) > 0;
```

From documentation.

> find_in_set(string str, string strList) Purpose: Returns the position
>   (starting from 1) of the first occurrence of a specified string within
>   a comma-separated string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL, 0
>   if the search string is not found, or 0 if the search string contains
>   a comma. Return type: int

Depending on your impala version you will need use regexp_replace instead of replace (if replace is not available)

Comment: I don't think this answers a question. Please look at the test data. Sure, I can cast one variable as a string, but on one side I will have `1` and on the other `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @addmeaning, fixed :)